Cannot create archive for publishing MAUI project in Visual Studio for Mac or Windows
I have a .NET MAUI project that I converted from Xamarin, it builds and debugs fine and all of the provisioning profiles are found. Ultimately I am trying to get it published on App Store Connect.
However, when I select "Archive for Publishing" in Visual Studio for Mac, it does not appear to do anything. It lists my previous archives and nothing else happens.
On Visual Studio for Windows the option to Archive has disappeared from all the menus for this project.
How can I fix or troubleshoot this issue?
Update: Using the "Publish" feature on Visual Studio for Windows, I get an error saying it failed to create app archive withe the following details in the output:
Archiving App Bundle 'ASIMobile'...
Build properties for C:\VSLocal\ASI Applications\Applications\ASI Mobile MAUI\Take2\ASIMobile\ASIMobile.csproj: VisualStudioProcessId: 21304, SolutionPath: C:\VSLocal\ASI Applications\Applications\ASI Mobile MAUI\Take2\ASIMobile.sln, SolutionName: ASIMobile, RunConfiguration: Default, ArchiveOnBuild: False, ArchivePath: , IsAppDistribution: False, DeviceSpecificBuild: false, TargetiOSDevice: , _iOSRuntimeIdentifier: ios-arm64, IsHotRestartBuild: False, MessagingVersion: 17.2.8053, _DotNetRootRemoteDirectory: /Users/asiadmin\Library\Caches\Xamarin\XMA\SDKs\dotnet/, ServerSshPort: 22, ServerTcpPort: 55461, ServerUser: ASI Admin, ContinueOnDisconnected: False, ServerAddress: 192.168.30.106
Build properties for C:\VSLocal\ASI Applications\Applications\ASI Mobile MAUI\Take2\ASIMobile\ASIMobile.csproj: VisualStudioProcessId: 21304, SolutionPath: C:\VSLocal\ASI Applications\Applications\ASI Mobile MAUI\Take2\ASIMobile.sln, SolutionName: ASIMobile, RunConfiguration: Default, ArchiveOnBuild: False, ArchivePath: , IsAppDistribution: False, DeviceSpecificBuild: false, TargetiOSDevice: , _iOSRuntimeIdentifier: ios-arm64, IsHotRestartBuild: False, MessagingVersion: 17.2.8053, _DotNetRootRemoteDirectory: /Users/asiadmin\Library\Caches\Xamarin\XMA\SDKs\dotnet/, ServerSshPort: 22, ServerTcpPort: 55461, ServerUser: ASI Admin, ContinueOnDisconnected: False, ServerAddress: 192.168.30.106
Cannot create an IOS archive 'ASIMobile'. Process cannot be executed on XMA server.
The "Unzip" task failed unexpectedly.
System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at Xamarin.MacDev.CompressionHelper.TryDecompressUsingSystemIOCompression(TaskLoggingHelper log, String zip, String resource, String decompressionDir) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks/Decompress.cs:line 200
   at Xamarin.MacDev.CompressionHelper.TryDecompress(TaskLoggingHelper log, String zip, String resource, String decompressionDir, List`1 createdFiles, String& decompressedResource) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks/Decompress.cs:line 104
   at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.Unzip.ExecuteLocally() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks/Tasks/Unzip.cs:line 61
   at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.Unzip.Execute() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks/Tasks/Unzip.cs:line 43
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()

On the Visual Studio for Mac side of things, I finally got the archive build to return an error. The warnings my project had were preventing it. This is the error for VS for Mac:
The "ReadItemsFromFile" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowWithoutLineInfo(String res)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(Stream stream, LoadOptions options)
   at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.ReadItemsFromFileBase.Execute() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks/Tasks/ReadItemsFromFileBase.cs:line 40
   at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.ReadItemsFromFile.Execute() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks/Tasks/ReadItemsFromFile.cs:line 13
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask)

However, this error clears on a clean/rebuild and I am left with it returning nothing again.

Have you follow these steps to Publish an iOS app for App Store distribution? If you use Visual Studio for Windows, In Solution Explorer, right-click on your .NET MAUI app project and there is a  Publish  that you can select.

@LiqunShen-MSFT Yes, when following these steps in Visual Studio for Windows, I get an error saying "Failed to create App archive 'ASIMobile'.

Can this project build in a release and debug mode?

@LiqunShen-MSFT Yes, it can build successfully in both release and debug.

Another way is that you could generate the ipa file in ios project settings.  And use Transporter to submit to upload your ipa file.
